# Pass a function that uses other functions as parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, parameters, typeerror

I am developing a project in Typescript that has two classes like this:

```
class A{

  //some attributes

  function_to_pass(){
    //Do something
    this.someFunction();
    //Make changes in object A
  }

  protected someFunction(){
    //Do some stuff
  }

}
```

```
class B{
  
  private readonly _functionProvided: () => void;

  constructor(functionProvided: () => void){
    this._functionPassed = functionProvided;
  }

  private myFunction(){
    //Do some stuff
    this._functionProvided();
  }

}
```

I want the object of class B to call the "function_to_pass" method in the object of class A, so i pass the function as a parameter in the constructor and then call "myFunction" in this object b. Like this

```
objectA = new A();

objectB = new B(objectA.function_to_pass)

objectB.myFunction()
```

But, i get the following error:

```
TypeError: this.someFunction is not a function
```

I suppose that objectB does not know about objectA, so objectB can't manipulate objectA.

Is there anyway i can do this?

Comment: ObjectB.myFunction didnt you declare it private ? Have you tried changing scope to public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems with the code, the first I think is a typo: the `class B` constructor doesn't initialize the instance data, `_functionProvided`. (see FIX #1)

The second problem is the real problem, and has to do with the execution context of `function_to_pass`. In order that `this` be defined when it runs, the function must be bound to its instance.  See (FIX #2).

```
class A{

  //some attributes

  function_to_pass(){
    //Do something
    this.someFunction();
    //Make changes in object A
  }

  protected someFunction(){
    //Do some stuff
  }

}

class B{
  
  private readonly _functionProvided: () => void;

  constructor(functionProvided: () => void){
    // FIX #1, no such thing as _functionPassed
    // WAS: this._functionPassed = functionProvided;
    this._functionProvided = functionProvided;
  }

  private myFunction(){
    //Do some stuff
    this._functionProvided();
  }

}


let objectA = new A();

// FIX #2: bind the receiver of function_to_pass
// WAS: objectB = new B(objectA.function_to_pass)
let objectB = new B(objectA.function_to_pass.bind(objectA));

objectB.myFunction()
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! The typo was my mistake while writing the question. The .bind was all I needed. Thank you very much.